# Add Metadata to columns in tables

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, metadata

Hi there so I have Postgres and MySQL databases with lots of tables. Currently I’ve been asked to document the columns in all the dbs if they have PII info. Obviously keeping this in an external document isn’t great since It can get out of date.

I was wondering if there was a way to annotate columns with metadata. For instance a flag (`PII`) or a Boolean flag (`PII=true`) on each columns so our data dictionary can stay up to date. Additionally allowing to annotate this info whenever we add a new column to a table.

Comment: Personally I've never seen the point , it doesn't matter where the 'metadata' is stored it always gets out of date and is never faithfully maintained, You need really tight change control and that never happens either..Somehow the business doesn't value documentation or recognise it as a chargeable item. (rant over)

Comment: @P.Salmon As Yoda said, "That... is why you fail."

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres you can use [comment on column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html), e.g.

```
comment on column some_table.some_column is 'PII=true';
```

I don't know if MySQL has something similar.

Comment: Yes, MySQL supports comments as metadata on tables, columns, indexes, and partitions. The length limit is 1024 characters. They appear in the information_schema or when you use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html